# Blank space at bottom of page outside the html tags on mobile after giving a width that exceeds 100% to an element

Tags: html, css

> Honestly believing I must be the first to encounter this problem after
>   searching the web for quite a bit, I decided to present this issue to
>   you.

### The issue

The issue I am facing resembles a *"blank space"* that lives at the bottom of my page. It's only visible on mobile and I haven't been able to replicate the issue on desktop, however going into developer modus on chrome and visiting my website, I can see the problem.

When using the developer mode in chrome and checking all the elements, it becomes apparent that the *"blank space"* is *nothing*. It holds no information and it doesn't *seem* tied to any element.

However, after some digging it was found it the *"blank space"* only pops up after giving width to an element. And not just a width, but a width that exceeds the view-port.

Something else that caught my attention is that the height of this *"blank space"* is the same as the view-port height.

### What am I trying to accomplish

You might wonder why I am setting a width exceeding the view-port, my reasoning for this is because I am trying to build a mobile(only) website that uses horizontal scrolling as a way to paginate between different content.

My goal is to accomplish this solely using css3 and html, no jQuery, no JavaScript and preferably not any ready-made plugins.

So far the *"horizontal scroll"* gives me the desired effect apart from the massive amount of white space it gives on the bottom of my page. I'd like to invest my time into trying to "fix" it rather than replacing it.

### Recreating the issue

The easiest way to re-create my issue is to start off with a blank html file and give it the following elements:

```
<div id="wrapper"> ... </div>
```

And inside the wrapper put:

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Then in your css file put the following styles:

```
body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 200vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

And don't forget to include a meta tag in the `<head></head>` for the view-port:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**For a live example, please check [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehwshurz/).**

### Edit:

Adding some screenshots of my chrome developer tool to visualize the issue.

See here the actual website content, as you can see all is like intended.
The width is `200vw` and height is `100vw`.
[image: Visualization of the "blank space" issue. Normal website content.]

See here the issue captured as a "blank space" like described in the OP.
Notice that the blank space stretched to twice the height of the `height: 100vh` as set in the css styling. Width stretched as far as the content, `width: 200vw`.
[image: Visualization of the "blank space" issue. The "blank space" captured.]

*Chrome developer tools screen-size in device modus (`CTRL - SHIFT - M`) is 360x640 (width x height).*

Comment: chrome developer tool bug ?

Comment: @afelixj this crossed my mind, however my chrome browser on my android phone is displaying the same issue identical to the developer tool.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when there is a width > `100vw` so a horizontal scroll bar appear and take a height from the page height so a new vertical scroll bar appear and affect the height of the page

Here is the issue
[image]
So the solution is to give body a width of 100% then overflow-x:hidden
and then it become

[image]

**Edit**
and here a new screenshot with device dev tools enabled

[image]

```css
    body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
   #wrapper {
    width: 200vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

and updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ehwshurz/3/)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not give me the desired effect. Both of the `table-cells` are visible and there is no horizontal scroll.

Comment: Yes I am working on a different solution and will edit my answer sorry for that!

Comment: @OlavA Check my edited answer please and the updated fiddle as well, thanks!

Comment: @PeterWilson Leaving the html as it is in the OP, and changing my css code with the code you provided is now giving me the horizontal scroll function. However the issue of the "blank space" as explained in the OP persists.

Comment: @OlavA I am sorry the `body` only need to be changed and the rest of your css has no problems I edit it now again I am sorry again for that but the issue really wired :)

Comment: @OlavA see the screenshot also for more explanation

Comment: @PeterWilson Running your updated code the "blank-space" issue still persists, I notice you are checking it in the chrome developer tools window but have not selected the "device" option. Can you toggle `Device Mode` (`CTRL - SHIFT- M`) in the developer tools window and see if the issue shows?

Comment: @OlavA Sure I will check it again

Comment: @OlavA I checked it and the issue disappeared and a new screenshot no attached to my answer

Comment: @PeterWilson Please check the edited OP, I added 2 screenshots to visualize the "blank-space" issue. Can you confirm you aren't running into the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height:100vh;
overflow-y:none;
}
```

Comment: Correct, setting an `overflow-y` of `hidden` (which I think you meant) did not solve the issue, neither did adding the `height` of `100vh` in combination or on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works great when I tried it out:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/qZZxRG. Toggle the `background` elements and you'll see it works just as you want.

The only difference is that I used [`normalize.css`](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) behind the code. Perhaps this gets a code gremlin you might have missed. Normalize is a great way to get rid of some HTML oddities and it's very light weight.

Comment: Leaving the code as it is in the OP, besides adding `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">` to the `<head></head>` did not solve the issue. However from chrome developer tools it does seem like your provided codepen link worked correctly. Very odd.

Comment: If it's a browser scrollbar application issue, you really can't control that as far I know. Using `vh` should cover you. The code works though, that much is certain.

Comment: @OlavA You may also have missed that staypuftman has suggested using a javascript library that you need to download and install on your server. The link to download is in their answer. If all you did is add the `link` line to your header, without installing the library, then it won't find and use the library.

Comment: @AntonChanning Do you mean the `normalize.css` library? I did download and install this library. I am aware that just setting a link in the `<head></head>` tag is not going to work without the files present on the host.

Comment: Just checking. All levels of users on this site and from your comment it wasn't clear... ;-)